# Why can't I undo my vote on comment?

Tags: discussion, support

I acidentally up-voted a comment on my question. But I'm unable to undo it. When I touch the red triangle nothing happens. Is it a bug or there's a reason?

I tried on other comments and I was able to undo my vote. This is the only comment I can't undo my vote on.

Comment: Now I see that comment is edited. I don't know if the edit is done before my vote or after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are restrictions preventing you from undoing votes on various content on the platform.

For more information see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/166366).  The answer does not specifically address comments, but I am pretty sure I have seen similar restrictions to changing your mind on votes on comments too. I suspect you attempted to remove your vote after 5 minutes had elapsed.

> Exception one: you may remove your vote within a five minute window from the time of the last vote you cast on that post.

In general if you have questions about the operation of the software of the site, it is best to check [Meta StackExhange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) the behavior here is common to all StackExchange sites.

Comment: 5 minutes is the time that you can't edit your comment after that. It has nothing to do with the votes on them.

Comment: Please see the section on "Limits on changing votes".  I quote: "Exception one: you may remove your vote within a five minute window from the time of the last vote you cast on that post."

Comment: I suspect you are incorrect in saying it is the "only comment I can't undo my comment on" - I have just tried.  I can undo on recent votes, I cannot undo on votes I made yesterday.

Comment: Confirmed empirically - 5 minute timer on comment votes. Before 5 mins - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOFui.png After, no response.